# how to sort json array value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to convert this json into html table with sorted date wise. Basically my JSON data comes through looking like this:

Here I want to recurrenceList dates

```
  var frequencyList=  [
      {
        "project": "abc",
        "recurrenceList": [
          "2021-09-16",
          "2023-09-16",
          "2025-09-16"
        ]
      },
      {
        "project": "xyz",
        "recurrenceList": [
          "2021-08-23",
          "2025-08-23"
        ]
      },
      {
        "project": "mno",
        "recurrenceList": [
          "2021-09-11",
          "2022-05-11",
          "2023-01-11",
          "2023-09-11",
          "2024-05-11",
          "2025-01-11",
          "2025-09-11"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I am getting output like this
[image]
expected output in html table with two columns given below (based on above JSON)

```
project name   reminder date
xyz              2021-08-23
mno              2021-09-11
abc              2021-09-16
mno              2022-05-11
```

etc...

Below code for Ajax to get the JSON DATA  frequencyList

```
/* the getPaymentPlan function is standalone, it should not be within a loop or within any other callback functions! */
const getPaymentPlan = ({
  dateFrom,
  dateTo,
  recurrenceDate,
  daysBefore,
  period,
  skip,
  title
}) => {
  //start from either the recurrence start date, or the start date in the form - whichever is later
  let startDate = (recurrenceDate.getTime() > dateFrom.getTime() ? recurrenceDate : dateFrom);
  //reminders go out several days before the actual recurrence start date
  startDate = startDate.subtractDays(daysBefore);

  let recurObj = {
    "project": title,
    "recurrenceList": []
  }

  while (startDate.getTime() <= dateTo.getTime()) {
    recurObj.recurrenceList.push(startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);

    switch (period) {
      case 'Monthly':
        startDate = startDate.addMonths(parseInt(skip));
        break;
      case 'Yearly':
        startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() + parseInt(skip));
        break;
      default:
        recurObj.recurrenceList.push("wrong period type is given")
        break;
    }
  }

  return recurObj;
}

/* below are some functions to correctly add / subtract days and months from a Date, accounting for leap years, differing month lengths, etc */
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

Date.prototype.subtractDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
  return date;
}

Date.prototype.addMonths = function(months) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  var d = date.getDate();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
  if (date.getDate() != d) {
    date.setDate(0);
  }
  return date;
}
    $('#find_recurrence').click(function(event) {
        
         $('.tableinvoicelist_all').find('tbody').remove();
         
    var getID_comp = $('#getID_comp').val();
  var fromdate_recu_viewedit = $('#fromdate_recu_view').val(); //2025-01-01
  var fromdate_recu_view = fromdate_recu_viewedit.split("-").reverse().join("-");
  var todate_recu_viewedit = $('#todate_recu_view').val(); //2026-01-30
  var todate_recu_view = todate_recu_viewedit.split("-").reverse().join("-");
  
  //hard-code data instead of AJAX, for this demo:
  
   $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "index.php/welcome/list_all_projects_reminder/",
            
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "company_id": getID_comp
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var new_datajson = JSON.parse(data);
  let new_data = new_datajson;

  let inputList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < new_data.projectremindshow.length; i++) {
    var proj = new_data.projectremindshow[i];

    //add a new entry to inputList for each entry returned from the AJAX call
    inputList.push({
      dateFrom: new Date(fromdate_recu_view),
      dateTo: new Date(todate_recu_view),
      daysBefore: proj.reminder_set_days,
      recurrenceDate: new Date(proj.start_date),
      period: proj.period_type,
      skip: proj.recur_every,
      title: proj.project_title
    });
  }
  
   const frequencyList = inputList.map((el, index) => {
    return getPaymentPlan(el)
  });
  
  console.log(frequencyList);
   $.each(frequencyList, function(index, jsonObject){     
if(Object.keys(jsonObject).length > 0){
  var tableRow = '<tr>';
  $.each(Object.keys(jsonObject), function(i, key){
     tableRow += '<td>' + jsonObject[key] + '</td>';
  });
  tableRow += "</tr>";
 
  $("#tablereminder").last().append(tableRow);
}
});
   
            }
   })
 
});
```

How to change the list in one list instead of three list (*recurrenceList*)?
Sort with date wise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: @AminTaghikhani actually its not. My json format is different. my json contains another array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative version of the getPaymentPlan function which will output the data in a format which may be easier to sort, and also to output later according to your desired HTML format:

```
const getPaymentPlan = ({
  dateFrom,
  dateTo,
  recurrenceDate,
  daysBefore,
  period,
  skip,
  title
}) => {
  //start from either the recurrence start date, or the start date in the form - whichever is later
  let startDate = (recurrenceDate.getTime() > dateFrom.getTime() ? recurrenceDate : dateFrom);
  //reminders go out several days before the actual recurrence start date
  startDate = startDate.subtractDays(daysBefore);

  let recurrenceList = [];

  while (startDate.getTime() <= dateTo.getTime()) {
    recurrenceList.push({ "project": title, "reminderDate": startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0] });

    switch (period) {
      case 'Monthly':
        startDate = startDate.addMonths(parseInt(skip));
        break;
      case 'Yearly':
        startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() + parseInt(skip));
        break;
      default:
        recurrenceList.push({ "project": "wrong period type is given", "reminderDate": null })
        break;
    }
  }

  return recurrenceList;
}
```

You can then sort it using a comparison function similar to the examples available in earlier questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value):

```
function compare( a, b ) {
  if ( a.reminderDate < b.reminderDate ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.reminderDate > b.reminderDate){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

recurrenceList.sort( compare );
```

Once you've done that you can just loop through the list to generate the HTML table:

```
$.each(frequencyList, function(index, jsonObject){     
  var tableRow = '<tr>';
  $.each(Object.keys(jsonObject), function(i, key){
     tableRow += '<td>' + jsonObject[key] + '</td>';
  });
  tableRow += "</tr>";
 
  $("#tablereminder").last().append(tableRow);
});
```

Putting it all together in a demo, you can get the output you were looking for:

```js
$('#find_recurrence').click(function(event) {
  var fromdate_recu_view = $('#fromdate_recu_view').val(); //2025-01-01
  var todate_recu_view = $('#todate_recu_view').val(); //2026-01-30

  //hard-code data instead of AJAX, for this demo:
  let new_data = {
    "projectremindshow": [{
        "project_ID": "8",
        "project_title": "abc",
        "period_type": "Yearly",
        "recurrence_date": "2021-10-28",
        "reminder_set_days": "12",
        "recur_every": "2",
        "start_date": "2021-09-28"
      },
      {
        "project_ID": "10",
        "project_title": "xyz",
        "period_type": "Yearly",
        "recurrence_date": "2021-10-05",
        "reminder_set_days": "13",
        "recur_every": "4",
        "start_date": "2021-09-05"
      },
      {
        "project_ID": "11",
        "project_title": "mno",
        "period_type": "Monthly",
        "recurrence_date": "2021-10-01",
        "reminder_set_days": "10",
        "recur_every": "8",
        "start_date": "2021-09-21"
      }
    ]
  };

  let inputList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < new_data.projectremindshow.length; i++) {
    var proj = new_data.projectremindshow[i];

    //add a new entry to inputList for each entry returned from the AJAX call
    inputList.push({
      dateFrom: new Date(fromdate_recu_view),
      dateTo: new Date(todate_recu_view),
      daysBefore: proj.reminder_set_days,
      recurrenceDate: new Date(proj.start_date),
      period: proj.period_type,
      skip: proj.recur_every,
      title: proj.project_title
    });
  }

  let frequencyList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++)
  {
    let plan = getPaymentPlan(inputList[i]);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(frequencyList,plan);
  }
  console.log(frequencyList);
  frequencyList.sort(compare);

  $.each(frequencyList, function(index, jsonObject) {
    var tableRow = '<tr>';
    $.each(Object.keys(jsonObject), function(i, key) {
      tableRow += '<td>' + jsonObject[key] + '</td>';
    });
    tableRow += "</tr>";

    $("#tablereminder").last().append(tableRow);
  });


});

const getPaymentPlan = ({
  dateFrom,
  dateTo,
  recurrenceDate,
  daysBefore,
  period,
  skip,
  title
}) => {
  //start from either the recurrence start date, or the start date in the form - whichever is later
  let startDate = (recurrenceDate.getTime() > dateFrom.getTime() ? recurrenceDate : dateFrom);
  //reminders go out several days before the actual recurrence start date
  startDate = startDate.subtractDays(daysBefore);

  let recurrenceList = [];

  while (startDate.getTime() <= dateTo.getTime()) {
    recurrenceList.push({
      "project": title,
      "reminderDate": startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
    });

    switch (period) {
      case 'Monthly':
        startDate = startDate.addMonths(parseInt(skip));
        break;
      case 'Yearly':
        startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() + parseInt(skip));
        break;
      default:
        recurrenceList.push({
          "project": "wrong period type is given",
          "reminderDate": null
        })
        break;
    }
  }

  return recurrenceList;
}

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.reminderDate < b.reminderDate) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.reminderDate > b.reminderDate) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

Date.prototype.subtractDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
  return date;
}

Date.prototype.addMonths = function(months) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  var d = date.getDate();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
  if (date.getDate() != d) {
    date.setDate(0);
  }
  return date;
}
```

```css
#tablereminder
{
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#tablereminder td
{
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
From date: <input type="date" id="fromdate_recu_view" /><br/> To date: <input type="date" id="todate_recu_view"><br/>
<button id="find_recurrence">Find Recurrence</button>

<br/><br/>
<table id="tablereminder"></table>
```

(You may need to view the demo in full page mode to see the table as well as the debugging output from the console.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457789/how-to-filter-the-reminder-date-for-the-current-month

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the dates to timestamps and sort according to those timestamps, like:

```
const sortedDates = recurrenceList.map(date=>{
   const dateObj = {
      initial: date,
      timeStamp: new Date(
         Number(date.slice(0,4)),
         Number(date.slice(5,7)) - 1,
         Number(date.slice(8))
      ).getTime()
   }
   return dateObj
})
.sort((a,b) => a.timeStamp - b.timeStamp)
.map(obj=> obj.initial);
```

Comment: ```console.log(sortedDates)```